# Django MPTT queryset for instances with children with a certain attribute

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

I'm using [Django MPTT](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mptt/), with the model Foobar like this:

```
class Foobar(MPTTModel):
     parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

If I want to select all Foobars with children, I can do this:

```
[x for x in Foobar.objects.all() if x.get_children().exists()]
```

If I want to select all Foobars that have children with a certain attribute (like `published`), I can do this:

```
[x for x in Foobar.objects.all() if x.get_children().filter(published=True).exists()]
```

I can't work out a way to do this in one query, though. I need to do it in one query in order to be able to use it for the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) argument of `ForeignKey`:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    related_foobar = models.ForeignKey(
        Foobar,
        limit_choices_to=Q(....), # How do I make this work?
    )
```

Comment: Do you have a `parent` field specified via the `parent_attr` in `Foobar`s Meta ? And if so, what is the `related_name`?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I've edited my answer to include that info.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the pure property of being a parent is filtered for via the `__isnull` filter. This generally holds for reverse foreign key testing:

```
Foobar.objects.filter(children__isnull=False)  # must have children
```

It should be mentioned that `'children'` in this query is the `related_query_name` of the `ForeignKey`. This defaults to the `related_name` if that is provided or to the lowercase model name (`foobar` in this case).

With a concrete child property, you can simply do:

```
Foobar.objects.filter(children__published=True)
```

This will only include `Foobars` with at least one child that is published.